# Correctly format WiX bundle MSI Package Install Condition

Tags: c#, wix

I have an MSI that I need to install under certain conditions and I am struggling to work out how to write the condition to achieve it. I followed this page, http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_define_searches.html to produce this condition, and two product searches creating the variables.

```
<util:ProductSearch ProductCode="34DA9145-859A-4645-A0BD-6F22C551F8A9" 
                    Result="version" 
                    Variable="StandAloneMmaVersion"/>
<util:ProductSearch ProductCode="EE0183F4-3BF8-4EC8-8F7C-44D3BBE6FDF0" 
                    Result="version" 
                    Variable="AzureMmaVersion"/>

InstallCondition="StandAloneMmaVersion &lt; 8.0.110720.0 OR AzureMmaVersion &lt; 8.0.110720.0"
```

However when executed this produces the error message:

> Error 0x8007000d: Failed to parse condition "StandAloneMmaVersion < 8.0.110720.0 OR AzureMmaVersion < 8.0.110720.0". Unexpected character at position 24.

The page shows the < typed out but Visual Studio refused to build like that hence escaping them.

For bonus points what I would really like, but have not been able to find any examples of, is that I would like install condition to only affect install, not repair or modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Burn, version constants must have a `v` prefix:

```
StandAloneMmaVersion < v8.0.110720.0
```

Comment: Changed the condition to: InstallCondition="StandAloneMmaVersion &lt; v8.0.110720.0 OR AzureMmaVersion &lt; v8.0.110720.0" and got the error message Error 0x8007000d: Failed to parse condition "StandAloneMmaVersion < v8.0.110720.0 OR AzureMmaVersion < v8.0.110720.0". Invalid version format, at position 23. How do I correctly format a version?

Comment: Each field in a version must be no greater than 65535. 110720 isn't valid.

Comment: Assuming that the same constraint applies to the product search is there another way to achieve this or am I better off moving the logic to the bootstrapper and just setting a variable?

Comment: That's probably the best way.